# How to fix Google ads that force their way to the top of other divs on webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adsense

I have a site on Google App engine written in python/django/html. Site is located at http://perlesloyfer.no
Its a kind of blog that shows some images of people with a kind of bows i make. I have implemented a "sticky header" at the top, and im showing ads in the 9th position of the posts. But when i scroll the list the Google Ads are somehow forcing them self to be on top of the header. Image of this is in the bottom of the question.

What causes this, and is it possible to fix it? I want the ad to scroll like the other posts, but it should not show as it is "over" the header when its at that position.

Sticky header jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#sticky').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
            //$('#sticky').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', float: 'right'});
            $('#sticky').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('#sticky').removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

Actual HTML for the header:

```
<div id="sticky" class="top-area">
<div class="main-header"><a href="./">Perlesløyfer</a></div>
<div class="main-subheader"><p>Av Håkon Bogen</p></div>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=".">Bilder</li></a>
        <li><a class="selected" href="./about">Om</li></a>
        <li><a href="http://epla.no/handlaget/produkter/526979/">Kjøp</li></a>
        <li><a href="./submit">Last opp</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS for sticky:

```
#sticky {
    background-color: white;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Google Ad code:

```
<div class="commercial" id="page-wrap-ad">
    <p id="ads">
<!---  google_ad_client = ....  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script></p>
```

[image: Site displayed right]

[image: Google ad displaying wrong]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a greater z-index to the sticky header. Wasn't harder than that.

```
#sticky {
    background-color: white;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am allow to post this or not, but here goes:

Find the specific target element (div, class, etc) of the Ad in questions and use CSS to overwrite its positioning.

```
Example:
#myAnnoyingAd{
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I want the ad to scroll as the other elements do. But only it should not become "on top" of the header when its at the top